# How to correctly add syntax highlighting to all c typedef

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-c++, filetype-c

I saw that it's possible to manually add types to highlight, according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149478/how-can-i-teach-vim-about-additional-c-language-types-for-syntax-highlighting

However I was wondering if it's possible for vim to automatically highlight typedefs?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear—do you mean that you want, e.g., `typedef foo int` to now highlight all `foo`s as types? If you just use regex, it's likely to be buggy (`foo foo` is valid, and declares a variable `foo` of type `int`). You'd need a fully syntax parser that could then tell vim what to do.

Comment: yes that's what I mean. I wonder if the `YouCompletMe` plugin can do this, since its a supposed to be a code comprehension plugin.

Comment: If you use ctags (or adopting ctags is acceptable), then consider this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5842242/9447571